# How do I insert the value from another column?

Tags: r, conditional-statements

I want to fill a cell with a value from another column on the corresponding row.

I get the error message

```
Warning message:
In ukDataTest$s[is.na(ukDataTest$s) & !is.na(ukDataTest$s_2013)] <- ukDataTest$s_2013 :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

When I run:

```
ukDataTest$s[is.na(ukDataTest$s) & !is.na(ukDataTest$s_2013)] <- ukDataTest$s_2013
```

I presume this is because I am in effect assigning a whole column of values.

I want to assign the value on the corresponding row from ukDataTest$s_2013.

How do I do this?

Example data:

```
library(dplyr)
number <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
s <- c(0.1,NA,0.5,NA,0.8)
s_2013 <- c(NA,0.3,NA,0.7,NA)
cbind(number,s,s_2013)
```

Comment: You are having different sizes.  You need to have the same condition in both sides.  ukDataTest$s[is.na(ukDataTest$s) & !is.na(ukDataTest$s_2013)] <- ukDataTest$s_2013[is.na(ukDataTest$s) & !is.na(ukDataTest$s_2013)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about the reason for the error. The solution is to only try to replace with the corresponding rows from the other column, as in

```
ukDataTest$s[is.na(ukDataTest$s) & !is.na(ukDataTest$s_2013)] <- ukDataTest$s_2013[is.na(ukDataTest$s) & !is.na(ukDataTest$s_2013)]
```

Here's an example with some toy data

```
> dat <- data.frame(col1 = c(2, NA, 3, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA), 
+                   col2 = c(1, 1, NA, 2, 2, NA, NA, 4))
> 
> dat$col1
[1]  2 NA  3 NA  1  1 NA NA
> 
> dat$col1[is.na(dat$col1) & !is.na(dat$col2)] <- dat$col2[is.na(dat$col1) & !is.na(dat$col2)]
> 
> dat$col1
[1]  2  1  3  2  1  1 NA  4
```

Alternately, with the data that you posted in your question.

```
> number <- c(1,2,3,4,5)
> s <- c(0.1,NA,0.5,NA,0.8)
> s_2013 <- c(NA,0.3,NA,0.7,NA)
> 
> dat <- data.frame(number, s, s_2013)
> 
> dat$s[is.na(dat$s) & !is.na(dat$s_2013)] <- dat$s_2013[is.na(dat$s) & !is.na(dat$s_2013)]
> 
> dat$s
[1] 0.1 0.3 0.5 0.7 0.8
```

Comment: I have various rows where  `is.na(ukDataTest$s)&!is.na(ukDataTest$s_2013)` so this won't work

Comment: I'm not following this. If there are, say, 5 rows where `is.na(ukDataTest$s)&!is.na(ukDataTest$s_2013)`, then those five rows will be selected on both the right-hand side and the left-hand side of the assignment. If this doesn't work, can you post some data so we can see what the issue might be?

Comment: Joseph is right.  It makes sense.  It will work even if you have multiple rows where the item is true.  R will go row by row, and if a row of s  is found empty than it will replace that value with the corresponding row value in s_2013.  So it should work.  I know because I used this many times.

Comment: See above. I used the data you provided, and the result is what you should expect (i.e., the first NA gets filled in with .3 and the second with .7). Can you post an example for which the solution doesn't work?

Comment: You're right - apologies it was my data, I've got it working now

Comment: Awesome, glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Now they are the same size, and the whenever is.na(ukDataTest$s) & !is.na(ukDataTest$s_2013) is true, the corresponding row value of column s_2013 will be assigned to s.

```
    ukDataTest$s[is.na(ukDataTest$s) & !is.na(ukDataTest$s_2013)] <- ukDataTest$s_2013[is.na(ukDataTest$s) & !is.na(ukDataTest$s_2013)]
```